Compiling JS failed: 301940:101:')' expected at end of function call Buffer size 23200960
I started a new project using version 0.74.6 because I want to upgrade my old project, which is on version 0.64.4. I've been migrating code from the old project to the new one and installing libraries one by one. However, I'm now encountering an error.
I've checked for syntax issues but haven't found any.
I have tried
-npx react-native start --reset-cache
-npm cache clean --force
-> deleted node modules, clear cache ,deleted app from mobile and rebuild.
